# Вытягивание текста по высоте.

Tags: html, css

Как в HTML уменьшить текст в ширине и увеличить по высоте?

Comment: а по конкретней? Что Вам нужно сделать?

Comment: Допустим, есть длинный по ширине текст. Его нужно уменьшить по ширине, что бы было больше строк.

Comment: Уменьшить ширину контейнера (то есть блока, в котором находится текст), не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для строки:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Хороший вариант.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

свойствами `font-weight`, `font-stretch`, `font-size`  через таблицы стилей

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно.